# Concatenate two strings with a null in the middle

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm trying to build a string that consists of two variables that are divided by a null terminator. It must be done this way for the custom protocol we're using.

```
const char* vendorChar = "3333-3333-4444-aaa3-3333";
const char* userChar = "someUsername";

char usernameString[strlen(vendorChar) + strlen(userChar) + 1];
char* uPtr = usernameString;

strcpy(uPtr, vendorChar);
strcpy(uPtr+strlen(vendorChar)+1, userChar);
```

When I run the above code, it only sends over the value of vendorChar and ignores userChar. When it is working it should look like

```
4444-2222-3333-1111\0someUsername
```

So far I've learned that `str` functions will drop the null as it sees it at the end of the string. I think I have to use `memcpy` to preserve it, but I can't figure out how to.

Comment: Are you using a debugger to find out the value of uPtr? Those usually stop displaying the contents of a C string when they hit the \0. The second string may be there, just not displayed.

Comment: the null character STOPS string reading.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Are you sure it's not working for some other reason? Try to step through a debugger and print `uPtr` and `uPtr+strlen(vendorChar)+1`.

Comment: You have only shown the code that places the characters into `usernameString`. You have not shown the code that “sends over” the contents of `usernameString`. Show that code.

Comment: your code is not C, it is Objective-C,

Comment: @godel9 I'm using wireshark to intercept the packet

Comment: Likely not the problem, but `usernameString` is two short; it needs `+ 2` instead of `+ 1`, one additional element for each of the two null characters you will have (one in the middle and one at the end).

Comment: @claptrap C can be used in Obj-c, which is what I'm doing. The compiler is an Obj-C one, yes, but I'm dealing with C functions which is why I need this to be tagged with `C`

Comment: but your code snippet would not compile on a C compiler

Comment: @EricPostpischil That code has been in place and is already working in our current implementation. I'm only changing the value of usernameString that's being sent over.

Comment: @Chris: Show the code. You should present [a self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @claptrap: According to [the Wikipedia page for Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), Objective-C is a strict superset of C. Per the C standard, clause 4, a conforming implementation is one that accepts any strictly conforming program. Therefore, an Objective-C compiler is a C compiler. Thus, this code, if it compiles in an Objective-C compiler does compile in a C compiler. Furthermore, since the code is accepted by a conforming implementation, a program formed with it that is otherwise acceptable is a conforming C program. (It is not strictly conforming.)

Comment: @Chris Now you have changed your code to C code, now your C tag is correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if the OP shows code that contains both ObjC code and C code then tagging it only C is not correct - it even contradicts your "self-contained compilable example" reference since one cannot compile the snippet with a C compiler. That said the whole thing is not so important to mention, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in your assumption, strcpy may copy up to the middle null char,
according to [this](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html), `strcpy(char *str1, const char *str2)` does this:

> > Copies the string pointed to by str2 to str1. Copies **up to** and including the null character of str2. If str1 and str2 overlap the behavior is undefined.

memcpy should solve the problem as it just treats the memory as a chunk of bytes, not as a string.

strcpy signature:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

memcpy signature:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

So just replace the name and add the cumulative lengths (with both null chars of course).

**EDIT**

To eliviate some doubts raised here, consider this code:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {

    char x[10] = {0};
    char y[10];
    char z[10];
    x[0] = x[1] = x[5] = 'a';
    memcpy(y,x,10);
    strcpy(z,x);
    printf ("y[5]= %s\n", &y[5]);
    printf ("z[5]= %s\n", &z[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

results is:

```
y[5]= a
z[5]=
```

So it's clear that memcpy moved the entire length, including byte [5], while strcpy did not, stopping at the null termination

Comment: @EricPostpischil, can you please explain how strcpy is *not* the problem if it behaves as the quote above?

Comment: If you are suggesting that `strcpy` is the problem because it is used to copy `uPtr` later, in code that is not shown, they you are right if that is indeed how `uPtr` or `usernameString` is being copied. I thought you were suggesting the `strcpy` calls in the code we have been show so far were a problem. They are not.

Comment: I changed both of my `strcpy`s to `memcpy` with the correct size, and it works! Except for one thing, it also sends over a byte of garbage. So when I look at the packet it looks like `3333-3333-3333.someUsername.!.`  the `.` being the null terminator

Comment: @EricPostpischil, oh, I was only referring to his assumption that strcpy would stop at null, edited a bit. Chris, could you be calculating the length incorrectly? (like adding the null chars twice?)

Comment: @Leeor That cleared it up. The garbage byte was coming from a miscalculated length. I added 1 to the second memcpy: `memcpy(uPtr, userChar, strlen(userChar) + 1)` and it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* vendorChar = [vendorId cStringUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
const char* userChar = [dsUsername cStringUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

char usernameString[strlen(vendorChar) + strlen(userChar) + 2];
char* uPtr = usernameString;

strcpy(uPtr, vendorChar);
memcpy(uPtr+strlen(vendorChar)+1, userChar, strlen(userChar) + 1);
```

Changes: I added space for the trailing `\0`, the `userChar` string is copied with trailing `\0` included.

Comment: `strcpy` is not the problem. It places a null character in the destination after the string.

Comment: Good answer, but please add an explanation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil one of the problems is with the size of `usernameString`. It should be `strlen(vendorChar) + strlen(userChar) + 2` instead of `strlen(vendorChar) + strlen(userChar) + 1`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: It is unlikely that is the problem. It would cause the final null character to be written beyond the array, but that will not necessary cause a subsequent write or transmission of `usernameString` to include only the vendor text and not the user text. It is much more likely that the method being used to write or transmit `usernameString` stops at the first null character it encounters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, I should rephrase that; I meant "one of the problems". I think that the function sending the content is stopping at the first null character.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need usernameString[] to be like -

```
char usernameString[strlen(vendorChar) + strlen(userChar) + 3];
```

because 1 is for putting "\", 1 for "0" and the other 1 is for null terminator, so becomes 3. Then use strcat() create the string you need. Like, below:

```
strcpy(uPtr, vendorChar);
strcat(uPtr,"\\");
strcat(uPtr,"0");
strcat(uPtr, userChar);
```

Comment: The OP does not want a literal “\0” in the buffer; they want a null character.

Comment: Umm... i think on last line questioner says, he want to *preserve* it? BTW, what does OP means?

Comment: @rakib OP = original poster